# Compiler warning/error for buffer over flow in dest object with memcpy

Tags: c

while Copying the data from const string to an array-(-> which is a member of structure) using memcopy, compiler throwing error for buffer overflow in dest object

Thanks for the learnings.

```
#define LEN 9
typedef struct buff_ {
....
..
char bowl[LEN];
}buff;
buff *dest= NULL;
dest= malloc......();// This is allocated properly
'
'
'
memcpy(dest->bowl,"y",LEN); //compiler throwing error here:buffer overflow
```

There shouldn't be any error as I am copying the string in to buffer(dest) which  LEN greater than the src.

Comment: `"y"` has length of 2, but you are attempting to copy `LEN`, which is `9`.

Comment: `strcpy()` is probably better-suited here.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  corrected with size of the source. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using, this will limit to LEN or actual length of the string whichever is smaller:

```
strncpy(dest->bowl,"y",LEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually it was read error that I am getting.  Reading "overflow". I've corrected it with size of the source address.